# android inputstream images directly into SQL Network

Tags: android, sqlite, inputstream

I know to import pictures into BMP is:

```
String  t1="http://www.xxx.xxx/xx/xx.jpg";
URL TKs = new URL(t1);
InputStream Is= TKs.openStream();       
Bitmap Bp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(Is);
Is.close();
```

I also know that put pictures into a format that can be stored in SQL:

```
is = resources.openRawResource(R.drawable.xxx);
byte[] image2 = new byte[is.available()];
is.read(image2);
is.close();
```

I use both methods should be able to reach my goal:

```
String  t1="http://www.xxx.xxx/xx/xx.jpg";
URL TKs = new URL(t1);
InputStream Is= TKs.openStream();       
byte[] image2 = new byte[Is.available()];
//////////////////the image2 is NULL
Is.read(image2);
Is.close();
```

Obviously I failed
I would like to ask me how to do it in the end?

Answer (score 0):

```
public byte[] getImage(String t1) throws Exception{  
        URL url = new URL(t1);  
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();  
        conn.setConnectTimeout(5 * 1000);  
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");  
        InputStream inStream = conn.getInputStream();  
        if(conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){  
            return readStream(inStream);  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  

   public static byte[] readStream(InputStream inStream) throws Exception{  
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
        int len = 0;  
        while( (len=inStream.read(buffer)) != -1){  
            outStream.write(buffer, 0, len);  
        }  
        outStream.close();  
        inStream.close();  
        return outStream.toByteArray();  
    }  

byte[] data = getImage(t1);
```